# How many French words do I need to learn to survive in France?

Tags: vocabulaire, apprentissage

Suppose I'm to live in France, working there.
How big a vocabulary shall I have, or, how many words shall I know, in order to be able to survive there?
I know this question is a bit vague, but please just try give some ball-park number? 2000? 5000? 10000?

**What I meant with "survive":**

When I first went abroad from China, my English was barely enough to "survive". For example, I sometimes forgot to use "stamp", instead I will ask post office officers "How can I buy some post ticket?"

So this *survive*, is just to live for basic needs, buying apparels, going to a restaurant, rent a flat, take transportations, and of course, work.

As I was just a VB programmer, working is also manageable with a limited vocabulary — I'm not a salesman or product owner that need talk to customers everyday.

Hope this explains my "concept" of "survive"…

Comment: This question is far too vague. How do you define "in order to survive"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be there and just live 2000
to work there 5000-8000 this depends on your profession!

Comment: merci beaucoup ! :)